# Editor for markdown tables

Tags: software-rec, editors, wiki

Is there any tool for linux which makes it easier to generate and edit tables for markdown?

Answer (score 5):

If you are Emacs user there are two modes that should help you if you are working with markdown.

First mode is [`markdown-mode`](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) that helps you with all typical markdown tags. In this major mode there are keyboard shortcuts for inserting links, images, headers, etc and for "compiling" markdown to html using third party apps (like [Markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) or [python-markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2)).

Tool that can help you with tables in markdown mode is [orgmode](http://orgmode.org/) that provides minor mode `orgtbl-mode`. This mode provides bindings to work with tables in format:

```
| Header | Test |
|--------+------|
|      1 | ?    |
|      2 | ?    |
```

When you turn it on, write `|some text` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> `orgtbl-mode` will add next `|`. <kbd>Tab</kbd> also allows you to change cells of table and aligning text and tables. There is also possibility to move colums/rows, killing them and more. Detailed instruction you can find in [The built-in table editor](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html) chapter in `org-mode` documentation.

Comment: indeed, assuming you are using emacs' markdown mode, you can even put this in your emac init file  `(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'turn-on-orgtbl)` and get org's table editor capabilities mixed into markdown-mode's capabilities.  Now, just add pandoc-mode!

Answer (score 3):

The best GUI I have found is provided by the web application [Markdown Tables](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[TableFlip](http://tableflipapp.com/) is a software designed specifically to be a Markdown table editor only. Currently, only available for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I know of [ReText](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/home/ReText/), not used if not to try, but seems promising.
It should support tables through markdown extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with macros in vim.

Use `qa` to record a macro named "a", `q` to stop recording, `@a` to play it back and `100@a` to play it back 100 times.

Comment: Im using emacs and don't know vim very well. Is it possible to do something similar in emacs?

Comment: @student: Yes, IIRC the key combination is C-x ( to start recording, C-x ) to stop and C-x e to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution similar to the Emacs one but prefer Sublime Text over Emacs, there is the [SublimeTableEditor](https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor).